# Implement/use foreign keys in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys

How can I implement a foreign key in SQLite?  I was thinking something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE job (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, employer_id INTEGER, ...);
CREATE TABLE employer(_id INTEGER, employer_name TEXT NOT NULL, ...);
```

Where `employer_id` is the `_id` from the table `employer`. Would this work? Is there another fast, maybe less prone to error way? Maybe with triggers?

Comment: I'm no sqlite guru, but are you using a version that doesn't enforce the key (although it supports the create syntax)? In that case, have a look at http://justatheory.com/computers/databases/sqlite/foreign_key_triggers.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I don't understand the question, but if it's the constraint you want, just do this:

```
ALTER TABLE Job
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (employer_id)
    REFERENCES Employer(_id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Comment: Is that legal SQLite code? I thought SQLite doesn't support foreign keys constraints?

Comment: @Mohit Deshpande: At least SQLite3 does, I don't know about earlier versions.

Comment: @Mohit: I was suprised too, but SQLite has foreign key support see http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html

Comment: @Mohit: If you're using SQLite 3.6.19 or later, foreign keys are supported. See http://www.hwaci.com/sw/sqlite/foreignkeys.html for details and how to enable it.

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt: does this really work? On SQLite 3.7.7 it gives syntax error; and according to documentation it's not supposed to work.

Answer (score 2):

See [SQLite (3.6.19) Foreign Key Support](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html)

(Earlier version of SQLite do not support enforced FK relationships.)