# SQLite - How to delete parent row while keeping the child/children rows?

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys

I understand the concepts of `PRAGMA foreign_key` and of `ON DELETE RESTRICT/NO ACTION`, but I am facing a different kind of situation.

I need to delete a parent row but keep the child row associated with it. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE A(id, name);
INSERT INTO A(id, name) VALUES (1, "Loreum");

CREATE TABLE B(id, id_A, name) FOREIGN KEY(id_A) REFERENCES A(id);
INSERT INTO B(id, id_A, name) VALUES (1, 1, "Opium");
DELETE FROM A WHERE id = 1;
```

I want to achieve this **while keeping the child row intact**. Is this possible at all?

**EDIT**

The example above separates my question from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22245084/1708390). Example might help some people, who only understand when there is code.

Comment: INTACT means? The id should still be in tableB?

Comment: yes, nothing happens to child row but parent is deleted. Yes data integrity will be violated but that is what i want :P

Comment: And this does not work with `no action` set?

Comment: yes, `NO ACTION` does not let me delete parent; throws error

Comment: Add `ON DELETE SET NULL` at the end of the definition of the foreign key on table B.

Comment: this will set the child row to NULL. I don't want that to happen. My requirement is, parent deleted and a new parent with same id inserted. UPDATE won't work either.

Comment: I am taking help from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17602862/1708390) answer. This states that `ON DELETE NO ACTION` will not allow you to delete parent. Basically SQLite is trying to preserve data integrity.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Delete Row ONLY in Parent Table which has a Foregin Key Reference in Child Table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22245084/how-to-delete-row-only-in-parent-table-which-has-a-foregin-key-reference-in-chil)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a [deferred foreign key constraint](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_deferred):

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = on;
CREATE TABLE A(id PRIMARY KEY, name);
INSERT INTO A(id, name) VALUES (1, "Loreum");
CREATE TABLE B(id, id_A, name, FOREIGN KEY(id_A) REFERENCES A(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED);
INSERT INTO B(id, id_A, name) VALUES (1, 1, "Opium");

BEGIN;
DELETE FROM A WHERE id = 1;
INSERT INTO A(id, name) VALUES (1, "another Loreum");
COMMIT;
```

Comment: look at that. That is the correct answer for this question, but sadly, this is not going to help me. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I have just seen [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22245195/1708390). Can you please tell me if this is the right approach; to drop the FK constraint?

Comment: Enforcing it is the whole point of a constraint. Whether a data model with dangling IDs is the right approach is something that you have to decide yourself.